# SSLError in python requests due to self-signed certificate

Tags: python, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I'm working for a company that has a an internal network. When I connect to the website *https://engine.my_company.com* through the browser everything is ok, even if I look at the certificates in the browser they seem legit. However if I run a request to the website with python:

```
url = "https://engine.my_company.com"
response = requests.get(url, verify=True))
```

I get:

> (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
> issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

I know I can put verify=False to make it work, but I would rather solve the issue.
I tried to save the 3 certificates that i see in the browser:

[image]

both as single certificate and as chain certificate:

[image]

and modify the code in this way:

```
response = requests.get(url, verify="/path_to_cert/certificate_1.cer"))
response = requests.get(url, verify="/path_to_cert/certificate_2.cer"))
response = requests.get(url, verify="/path_to_cert/certificate_3.cer"))
```

but I keep getting the same error.

I even tried to copy/paste the content of the three certificates in cacert.pem (solution that i don't like) located in:

```
import certifi
certifi.where()
```

but that also failed.

I also tried setting the environment variable REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE pointing to the chain of my certificates but still got the same error.

Any idea on how I could solve this?

Is this the right way to get the certificates (through the browser I mean)?

Comment: Normally you only need to worry about the root certificate in the chain, the certificate you have labeled #1. You *should* be able to save that single certificate in either PEM or DER form (the requests docs don't say so perhaps either will work) and set `verify=/path/to/root_cert.der` (or `root_cert.pem` if that works) in the `get` call. I haven't tried this myself yet so I'm not certain. I would avoid the CA_BUNDLE method unless you need to trust multiple root certificates.

Comment: I just tried it and it works with PEM formatted certs, not DER. So your attempt with `response = requests.get(url, verify="/path_to_cert/certificate_1.cer")` should have worked.

Answer (score -1):

One way around this is to set the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable prior to running the python code.

Comment: hi david, could you be more specific? set to what?

Comment: Point it to your .cer file. If more than one, you may have to chain them.