# Python3 Requests verify Cert-Path not working for self-signed leaf certificate

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, ssl-certificate

My team is trying to use python3-requests module with explicit server-authentication using the server-certificate. The server-certificate is a self-signed certificate (so there is no chain, no intermediate or root ca). The certificate itself is valid and hasn't expired.

As shown in:

- [Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror)
- or [How to get Python requests to trust a self signed SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405867/how-to-get-python-requests-to-trust-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate)

a path to a CA-Bundle-Certificate can be supplied for the `verify`-argument of the requests' get-method, i.e.

```py
cafile = 'cacert.pem' # http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
r = requests.get(url, verify=cafile)
```

or simiarly [SSLError in python requests due to self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76340986/sslerror-in-python-requests-due-to-self-signed-certificate)

```py
cafile = 'cacert.pem' # http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
r = requests.get(url, verify=cafile)
```

Another suggestion is to use the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` Variable, which in turn is used by the requests-module, but this didn't work either (check above SO-Posts to see how to use it).

Also I tried adding the certificate to the certifi supplied path (check [Python requests: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69196572/python-requests-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-sel))

```py
import certifi
certifi.where()
```

or

```py
import requests
requests.certs.where()
```

Please note:

- I'm aware of mTLS, the question is solely focused on server-sided certificate
- I tried both PEM and DER encoded certificates (whereas I'd expect it to be PEM-encoding)
- The self-signed certificate does not have a chain, it's a self-signed certificate.
- Python: 3.8.10, Requests: 2.28.2, certifi: 2022.12.7
- I'm working with a Windows 10 OS, WSL 2 running a Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS focal
- Throughout my research I haven't found a question focussing on a single-self-signed-leaf-certificate, that's where I suppose my issue differs from the listed questions.

So unfortunately all of the above methods have failed, i.e. the error message

`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<myhost>', port=<myport>): Max retries exceeded with url: <myurl> (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFIY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))` persisted.

Throughout all tries, the error-message hasn't changed.

The most frustrating thing is the second comment from: [SSLError in python requests due to self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76340986/sslerror-in-python-requests-due-to-self-signed-certificate)

`I just tried it and it works with PEM formatted certs, not DER. So your attempt with response = requests.get(url, verify="/path_to_cert/certificate_1.cer") should have worked.`

suggesting, that using the root-certificate from the example in pem-encoding seems to work, but the same setting using my self-signed certificate doesn't work :-(.

As stated in the 'Please note' section, the last bulletpoint, I have a "leaf-certificate", which by definition wouldn't be considered a ca-bundle (because the leaf-certificate isn't an issuing-ca, i.e. it's extendedKeyUsages aren't signingCertificates etc.) but I can't imagine that it really matters (because the relevant certificates in the path, namely just the self-signed, are present in the 'ca-bundle-file'.

Happy for any suggestion or hint :-)

Comment: Appendix: I'm already using `os.path.isfile(certpath)` to validate the existance (and correct pathing) of the self-signed certificate.

Comment: The `requests` documentation doesn't seem to clearly define what a CA_BUNDLE file is, so we have to guess (or look at the requests source code). Are you sure you are supplying the correct certificate in the `verify=` filename? How are you ensuring that the certificate your server sends is the one you have in your client-side cafile?

Comment: Aside from fiddling around locally (i.e. der / pem encoding etc), I'm using `ssl.get_server_certificate((server, port))` from https://pythontic.com/ssl/ssl-module/get_server_certificate and download it a step before the request method. So I can verify that it's the right certificateand it exists at the saved path.